# Bootstrap Weld 2.1.0 from void main

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi, bootstrapping, weld

How can I start an application with CDI that uses Weld within a normal Java SE environment, that is simply started from the command line and has no Glassfish or Tomcat in the background? With Weld 1.x you could do something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   final WeldContainer weld = new Weld().initialize();
   service = weld.instance().select(MyService.class).get();
}
```

But in Weld 2.x the initialize() is missing.

I can do something like this:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Main {
   @Inject
   Foo foo;

   public void main(@Observes ContainerInitialized event) {
       System.out.println("Starting application");
   }
}
```

This will inject Foo, but I want to pack my whole Application into a jar to be used by an other application that does not need to wait for Weld to actually start running. So I basically want a way to initialize Weld properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrapping Weld SE has not changed between Weld 1.x and 2.x, see the [reference manual](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/environments.html#d0e5659).

Just make sure to import `org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld`, not the new class `org.jboss.weld.Weld`.

Comment: Thanks. I used auto import from Netbeans and did not check my imports.